# How to read broken utf-8 text from popen?

Tags: python-3.x

I have simple code:

```
f = os.popen(command)
output = f.read()
```

result ( contains bad unicode symbols ):

```
nicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 822: invalid continuation byte
```

How to ignore this symbols ?

Comment: `If encoding or errors are specified, or universal_newlines is true, the file objects stdin, stdout and stderr will be opened in text mode using the encoding and errors specified in the call or the defaults for io.TextIOWrapper.`

Comment: if you think it is just starting on a bad byte and should be valid utf-8 then you can do errors='ignore'

Answer (score 0):

Simply using another encoding:

```
f = os.popen(command, encoding=<encoding goes here>)
output = f.read()
```